# Is there any performance loss when using ANSI data types in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, database-performance, database-administration, sqlperformance

If I use any ANSI supported data types like INTEGER, NUMERIC, REAL etc., as a data type for a column, or a variable in PL/SQL, will it have an additional cost for the database?

What are the pros and cons for using the ANSI supported data types in Oracle database? (Database Version: 19c)

Answer (score 3):

ANSI data-types are just aliases for Oracle data types and will be converted to the equivalent Oracle data type.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF):

> #### ANSI, DB2, and SQL/DS Data Types
>
> SQL statements that create tables and clusters can also use ANSI data types and data types from the IBM products SQL/DS and DB2. Oracle recognizes the ANSI or IBM data type name that differs from the Oracle Database data type name. It converts the data type to the equivalent Oracle data type, records the Oracle data type as the name of the column data type, and stores the column data in the Oracle data type based on the conversions shown in the tables that follow.
>
> | ANSI SQL Data Type | Oracle Data Type |
> | --- | --- |
> | `NUMERIC[(p,s)]` `DECIMAL[(p,s)]` (Note 1) | `NUMBER(p,s)` |
> | `INTEGER` `INT` `SMALLINT` | `NUMBER(38)` |
> | `FLOAT` (Note 2) `DOUBLE PRECISION` (Note 3) `REAL` (Note 4) | `FLOAT(126)` `FLOAT(126)` `FLOAT(63)` |

---

> What are the pros and cons for using the ANSI supported data types in Oracle database?

There are no performance benefits or penalties as the type will be converted to the equivalent Oracle type. The main benefit would be the portability of code between different RDBMS.

Comment: _"The main benefit would be the portability of code between different RDBMS."_   True, but I would argue that since - for many other issues - that 'code portability' tends to be a unicorn, there really is no point in not directly using the data types as oracle implements them.